# Rails routing two controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Firstly, I want to tell you that I am a novice in rails and I have a stupid question. I want to make an application where I should post news and every new will have have a category. So I create a controller about categories. Now, I add, edit and delete categories and I should create a controller about news but how should I connect news with categories in routes? I hope you understand my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Get a good Rails book. You won't have stupid questions then. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a story can only have one category, the model would be:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stories
end

class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

From the routing point of view, you can nest the resources:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :stories
end
```

or not:

```
resources :categories
resources :stories
```

This choice is up to you :)
See [Nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)